# Is AudioServicesPlaySystemSound allowed to use in App Store apps?

Tags: ios, audiotoolbox

The `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` function comes under System Sound Services. Is this service of AudioToolbox allowed to use?

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1012);
```

Or can it be rejected by Apple when submitting an app using it to the App Store?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes,** it is allowed to use. It's actually [documented in Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405248-audioservicesplaysystemsound).

There are some limitations on what you can play with this method though:

> Sound files that you play using this function must be:
>
> - No longer than 30 seconds in duration
> - In linear PCM or IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM) format
> - Packaged in a `.caf`, `.aif`, or `.wav` file

If you want level/timing control and the ability of playing multiple sounds at a time, use [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer) instead, it's the generally recommended method.

Comment: I just want to play default push notification sound, which seems is allowed. Thanks!